# WPF - Defining a xmlns based on another xmlns

Tags: xml, wpf, namespaces, hierarchy

Is there any way to declare a namespace like this :

```
xmlns:views="clr-namespace:xxx.xxx.Views"
xmlns:someNestedViews="views.SomeNestedView"
```

The objective is to speed up nested/repeated xmlns declarations and make them easier to read/maintain.

Comment: Interesting question, I'd like to know now!

Comment: Obfuscating something simple will probably introduce more problems than fix them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you need to include the whole CLR namespace: `xmlns:someNestedViews="xxx.xxx.Views.SomeNestedView"`. The `clr-namespace:` syntax maps a XAML namespace to a CLR namespace. It doesn't map to another XML namespace.

If you are the author of the classes in the `Views` namespace, you could use the [XmlnsDefinitionAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.markup.xmlnsdefinitionattribute?view=netframework-4.7.2) to specify a mapping between a XAML namespace and several different CLR namespaces, e.g.:

```
[assembly: XmlnsDefinition("http://yourlibrary.com/", "xxx.xxx.Views.")]
[assembly: XmlnsDefinition("http://yourlibrary.com/", "xxx.xxx.Views.SomeNestedView")]
```

This lessen the burden in XAML:

```
xmlns:viewsAndNestedViews="http://yourlibrary.com/"
```

Comment: In case someone would like to find some information about clr : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/cpp/dotnet/stl-clr-library-reference?view=vs-2017

Answer (score 0):

I've seen people use XML entities for this kind of thing

```
xmlns:x="&stem;/some.uri"
```

but although it's perfectly legal, I would be fairly appalled if I found that happening in XML that I wanted to work with. Mainly because it hints that the namespace might change at some point, and writing an application to process the XML when the namespaces might change is only going to make things more difficult.

Comment: Ok, i'll see if this helps ;)